# Excel VBA Code to merge similar adjacent cells

Tags: excel, vba, merge

I'd like to merge identical adjacent cells within a column. Some online examples loop through the column and merge every time the cell below matches, and I'd like to avoid that. Here's my current broken attempt that spits out run-time error 5.

```
Sub Merge2()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Dim rng1 As Range
    Dim rng2 As Range
    Dim certaincell As Range
    
    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = 0
    LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 35).End(xlUp).Row
    
    Set rng1 = Range(Cells(2, 35), Cells(LastRow, 35))
    
CheckUnder:
    For Each certaincell In rng1
        
        Set rng2 = Union(rng2, certaincell) 'Add the checking cell to the range
        
        If certaincell.Value = certaincell.Offset(1, 0).Value Then  'if the cell is the same as the cell under
            'move on to next cell
        
        Else
            rng2.Merge 'merge similar cells above
            Set rng2 = Nothing
            
        End If
        
    Next
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: rng2 is nothing when you first enter the loop. Union(Nothing, ...) is an illegal argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `rng2` is initially set to Nothing. So, adjust your code as follows:

```
For Each certaincell In rng1     
   If rng2 Is Nothing Then
      Set rng2 = certaincell
   End If
   Set rng2 = Union(rng2, certaincell) 'Add the checking cell to the range     
   If certaincell.Value = certaincell.Offset(1, 0).Value Then
   Else
      rng2.Merge 'merge similar cells above
      Set rng2 = Nothing
   End If     
Next
```

The if statement will check if the `rng2` is nothing and if so, it will assign the currently checked `certaincell` to the variable.
Also, merging cells with data will pop up some error dialogs. This can be avoided by using `Application.DisplayAlerts = False`.
Make sure to turn it on using `Application.DisplayAlerts = True` at the end.